# What's the fastest way to switch between a zero and non-zero integer value in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, performance

I have an integer "myInt" in some Objective-C code.  myInt is used as a boolean... hence I'm only interested in zero or non-zero values.  I'd like to quickly switch between zero and a non-zero value.  What's the fastest way to do this?

Here's what I've tried so far:  (All of these work)

**Try 1**:

```
// myInt is initialized to 0
if(myInt == 0){
    myInt = 1;
}else{
    myInt = 0;
}
```

**Try 2**:

```
myInt = !myInt;
```

**Try 3**:

```
myInt ^= 0xffffffff;
```

I realize I could just measure the performance with a profiler... however I decided to ask on SO because I hope that others (any myself) can learn something from the discussion motivated by this question.

Comment: It's okay if you're just asking for curiosity's sake, but if this is in a real app, chances are pretty good that this is not going to be the cause of any performance problems you encounter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try 2 is the most compact, cleanest, and easier to maintain. 
Why second guess the compiler's optimization?

Answer (score 3):

In general, to switch between 0 and some constant integer a, use

```
myInt = a - myInt
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  Are you compiling for ARM, x86_64, i386, PPC, or 6502?

The difference is academic, but if you really want to know which is faster you will have to look at the disassembled code generated by your compiler.